# Tag usernames on messages with the Facebook feed post wall API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Is it possible to send a message tagging a facebook user using Facebook Graph API? (from facebook PHP SDK)
I've tried the `@[id:1:name]` method, but it doesn't seems to work. Also, I tried using the `message_tags` parameter, but no luck. Have anyone done this before? As far as I know, Facebook disabled this option time ago; am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as what i know, it's not supported and it's not possible via their graph api, but i think i came across a link via google which shows a trick to tag anything with any link.etc.
Here it is: [Click here](http://crazydavinci.net/2011/05/tag-anyone-on-facebook-using-app/)

P.S I personally didn't test that trick, but i did try tagging using graph api but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried doing the trick but is not working. It was similar to the @[id:1:name] method.

Comment: No problem and yes it's similar to your method, i had tried this method very long back and it was working, may be it's patched now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check the Mentioning friends https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/